# Returning the whole list while taking the first N elements dynamically

Tags: python

Imagine having a parameter `N` which defines how many elements we need from a list, `my_list` and there is no limit for the lengths of the list.

It is simply done like this

```py
take_n = lambda my_list, N: my_list[:N]
```

```py
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
take_n(my_list, 2)  # output: [1, 2]
take_n(my_list, 10)  # output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

What to do if one wants to have the full list anyway?
Any cleaner approach than setting `N = 1e10` or a humongous number?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the fact that `my_list[:]` returns all the items, one can set `N = None` to achieve that.

```py
take_n(my_list, None)  # output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

In this case you can make sure it returns all the elements even if the list has gazillions of items.
In fact `my_list[: None]` is the same is `my_list[:]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a general solution that works with lists, tuples, or any other iterable, consider using `islice` from the `itertools` package.

```
from itertools import islice

sl = islice([1, 2, 3, 4], 3)
list(sl)  # [1, 2, 3]

sl = islice([1, 2, 3, 4], None)
list(sl)  # [1, 2, 3, 4]
```